# load row data based on the first filed in the row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

i have to develop new website for CAR Wash company , this company own three cleaning car which receive order from my system , max order per day for every car is 5 orders so i should add 5 green places beside every car in the the same car row . (ex) if car have two order so two fields with background yellow and other three fields in green background

I have two tables

1. Cars
2. Orders

Car table

```
ID  CarName
1    Car1
2    Car2
3    Car3
```

Order table

```
ID   ClientName   Phone       Date                         CarID
1       Jack      11111     22-7-2017 10:22:00 AM           2
2       Susan     22222     22-7-2017 01:30:00 PM           2
3       Hany      33333     22-7-2017 10:22:00 AM           3
4       Karim     44444     21-7-2017 08:22:00 AM           1
5       Halaa     55555     22-7-2017 05:22:00 PM           3
```

i want to select all orders for every car in one row per day based on selection of day from DATETIMEPICKER so i will select orders for 22-07

```
Cars                         Orders

car1           Empty     Empty     Empty  Empty Empty
car2           Jack(111111)  Susan(22222)  Empty  Empty Empty
car3           Hany(333333)  HalaSusan(55555)  Empty  Empty Empty
```

So how can do it if i use GridView and what is the best query

Comment: A fairly standard way of doing this is using [`STUFF FOR XML PATH('')`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=STUFF+FOR+XML+PATH)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Vehicle', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Vehicle;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #Vehicle (
    VehicleID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    VehicleName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
    );
GO 
INSERT #Vehicle (VehicleID, VehicleName) VALUES
    (1, 'Car1'), (2, 'Car2'), (3, 'Car3');
GO 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Orders;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #Orders (
    OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ClientName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    ServiceDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    VehicleID INT NOT NULL -- create FK refference back to Vehicle.VehicleID)
    );
GO 
-- create an  index to support the row_number() function...
-- The sort cost is greater than the difference between a seek & scan...
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Orders_VehicleID_ServiceDate
    ON #Orders (VehicleID, ServiceDate)
    INCLUDE (ClientName, PhoneNumber);
GO 
INSERT #Orders (OrderID, ClientName, PhoneNumber, ServiceDate, VehicleID) VALUES
    (1, ' Jack ', '11111', '07-22-2017 10:22:00 AM', 2),
    (2, ' Susan', '22222', '07-22-2017 01:30:00 PM', 2),
    (3, ' Hany ', '33333', '07-22-2017 10:22:00 AM', 3),
    (4, ' Karim', '44444', '07-21-2017 08:22:00 AM', 1),
    (5, ' Halaa', '55555', '07-22-2017 05:22:00 PM', 3);
GO 

--SELECT * FROM #Vehicle v;
--SELECT * FROM #Orders o;

--=======================================================================
DECLARE @WorkDate DATE = '2017-07-22';

WITH 
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            o.OrderID, o.ClientName, o.PhoneNumber, o.ServiceDate, o.VehicleID,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.VehicleID ORDER BY o.ServiceDate)
        FROM
            #Orders o
        WHERE 
            CAST(o.ServiceDate AS DATE) = @WorkDate
        )
SELECT 
    VehicleName = MAX(v.VehicleName),
    Order1 = MAX(CASE WHEN ar.RN = 1 THEN ar.ClientName + ' (' + ar.PhoneNumber + ')' ELSE '' END),
    Order2 = MAX(CASE WHEN ar.RN = 2 THEN ar.ClientName + ' (' + ar.PhoneNumber + ')' ELSE '' END),
    Order3 = MAX(CASE WHEN ar.RN = 3 THEN ar.ClientName + ' (' + ar.PhoneNumber + ')' ELSE '' END),
    Order4 = MAX(CASE WHEN ar.RN = 4 THEN ar.ClientName + ' (' + ar.PhoneNumber + ')' ELSE '' END),
    Order5 = MAX(CASE WHEN ar.RN = 5 THEN ar.ClientName + ' (' + ar.PhoneNumber + ')' ELSE '' END)
FROM
    #Vehicle v
    LEFT JOIN cte_AddRN ar
        ON v.VehicleID = ar.VehicleID
GROUP BY 
    v.VehicleID;
```

Results...

```
VehicleName Order1          Order2          Order3          Order4          Order5
----------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
Car1                                                                        
Car2         Jack  (11111)   Susan (22222)                                  
Car3         Hany  (33333)   Halaa (55555)
```